# Show that the pivots of A are positive if and only if A is symmetric positive definite

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I've been stuck on this question from a past exam for a while:

[image: Q1]

Firstly is my understanding of the pivot correct? In this case I said our $2$ pivots would be a, and $c-b^2/a$ (Subtract $b/a$ * the first row from the second). I get stuck on this step and am not so sure what to do.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $a$ and $c-b^2/a$ are pivots, so it remains to show that $A$ is SPD iff $a>0$ and $ac-b^2>0$ (by using the definition of the SPDness).

We have that $x^TAx>0$ if (why?) and only if
$$
\begin{split}
0&<\pmatrix{1\\0}^T\pmatrix{a&b\\b&c}\pmatrix{1\\0}=a,\\
\quad
0&<\pmatrix{t\\1}^T\pmatrix{a&b\\b&c}\pmatrix{t\\1}=at^2+2bt+c\quad\text{for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$}.
\end{split}
\tag{1}
$$
Note that $at^2+2bt+c$ is positive for all $t$ if and only if it has no real roots, that is, if the discriminant $(2b)^2-4ac=4(b^2-ac)$ is negative, which gives $ac-b^2>0$.